# Data edit problem for datetime input in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, edit

I have a create page which is I use the same page for edit. this page is for input and edit at the same time. I can input with any problem but I can't see the value of datetime variable when I click the edit button. all other data come true to the input area except datetime area. But it is working when I set it again and edit code is working well. Just there is writing gg.aa.yyy --:-- instead of a real value of which I want to edit data.

here is my input code:

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="product_expiration_date" name="product.expiration_date" />
```

here is my edit code:

```
else
{
    x.name = product.name;
    x.categories = product.categories;
    x.category_id = product.category_id;
    x.categories.id = product.category_id;
    x.category_id = product.category_id;
    x.price = product.price;
    x.count = product.count;
    x.expiration_date = product.expiration_date;
}
```

Comment: Yes, a `datetime-local` input has space for both date and time. If you just want to enter dates, use a `date` input.

Answer (score 0):

https://dotnetfiddle.net/ there is a .net fiddle

```
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    
    namespace HelloWorldMvcApp
    {
        
        public class SampleViewModel
        {
            public SampleViewModel()
            {
                this.FieldOne = "1";
                this.FieldTwo = "2";
                this.FieldThree = "3";
                this.FieldDate = DateTime.Now;
            }
            public string FieldOne { get; set; }
            public string FieldTwo { get; set; }
            public string FieldThree { get;set; }
            public DateTime FieldDate { get; set; }
        }
    }

    using System;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    namespace HelloWorldMvcApp
    {
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            [HttpGet]
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View(new SampleViewModel());
            }
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Index(HelloWorldMvcApp.SampleViewModel model)
            {           
                
                return View(model);
            }
        }
    }




   @model HelloWorldMvcApp.SampleViewModel-
   

    @{
        Layout = null;
    }
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!-- template from http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started -->
    
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        </head>
        
        <body>
                
        
                    @using (Html.BeginForm())
                    {
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FieldOne)
                            @Model.FieldOne
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FieldTwo)
                            @Model.FieldTwo
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FieldThree)
                            @Model.FieldThree
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FieldThree, new {@class="form-control"}) 
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FieldDate)
                            @Model.FieldDate
                            <input type="date" name="FieldDate" id="FieldDate" ></input>
                        </div>
                    
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-succes">Edit</button>
                    }
        
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                $('window').ready(function(){
                    $('FieldDate').datePicker();
                });
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

you want that bit of jquery to be added to your code

   

 

    
    $('window').ready(function(){
    $('#FieldDate').datePicker();
    });

Comment: mark answer by clicking tick button if you have your answer otherwise I am happy to add more information @gokce

Comment: It should be noted that this changes a lot of things about your code; it changes the `type` of the field to `date` from `datetime-local`. It add jQuery and Bootstrap to your dependencies, and old versions of both of those libraries at that. All for a single date picker component.